# Moving a WordPress site - Installation issue

Tags: urls, installation

I have moved Wordpress sites before and have occasionally encountered issues but always been able to resolve them. I have tried to do this several times with this site but I am still having the same problem installing WordPress at the new location.

My database seems to move over no problem and I can login to my site at [the admin](http://www.tassolarpanels.com.au/wp-admin/) but if I try to
[visit my site](http://www.tassolarpanels.com.au/) I just get the "index of" list of files.

I have put the contents of the WordPress install folder into /public_html/tassolarpanels.com.au. and I have added .htaccess file with 'DirectoryIndex index.php index.html' and I am still having no success.

Does any one know where my issue might be? I've tried following so many different instructions on moving wordpress and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is an `index.php` in the directory, and make that file the index file. Example for `.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Hi Toscho thanks for the response. There is a index.php file but I didn't have a .htaccess file in my directory so I created it and added the following: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress` 
but it didn't resolve the issue unfortunately. I'm really not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a lot of issues when moving a WordPress multisite. as a general rule, I usually start with a fresh vanilla WordPress site, go through the Multisite installation to ensure my `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess` files are setup correctly.

Then, I import my database, and go through all the tables needed - changing URLs and domains where necessary.

I made a [reference](http://ericholmes.ca/transferring-a-wordpress-multisite/) for myself on my website - feel free to give it a look.

I would double-check your `wp-config.php` file, make sure the domain and path are right in the multisite definitions, and from there - double check the tables I have listed in my post to make sure no blog post items are missing.

Also, perhaps check your `index.php` file permissions - perhaps it canot be read or seen? I'm not seeing it in the Index Of: list